Measuring the distance between golfball and hole on the ground
I have a question regarding measuring a distance with code/an AI model. I'm new to coding and I would like to make a code which can detect the distance between a golfball and the hole on a picture. The picture should be taken with a simple phone camera.
I already have a reliable object detection model which can detect the golf ball and the hole. I also thought of using the average size of a golfball and hole as a scale and solve it as a mathematical problem but I'm pretty sure this approach doesn't work.

You would need to show the code you are using for someone to assist you on StackOverflow.   The easy part is object detection, and drawing a line between two points.  The real problem is how would an AI even know how big certain things were in the picture to use as a scale to apply that ratio to the line in order to calculate the distance?

If, somehow, the location and objects in the background were identified, and dimensions of the object were trained, it might be able to identify a building, look up its dimensions, detect lines in the picture that could be used as vanishing points, and then perhaps figure out a ratio to use to put onto a line to measure it.

Sorry for the late answer, I wasn't able to come back to StackOverflow until now. There is no code yet. I was simply wondering how and if it's even possible. I know it's a really difficult task that might not be possible. Still, thanks for your answer!

Glad to be of help, it is possible if you had all the data to make it work, and that comes down to gathering the data by hand (like google does) or paying what ever api services that houses that data to use its info during each calculation.
